# Not able to push Appexchange upgrades

Tags: metadata-api, appexchange, spring15

I upgraded my package, however, i am not able to push upgrade due to the following error message:

> Salesforce Release in Progress The subscriber is not on the latest
>   release of salesforce.com. Once their organization is automaticaly
>   upgraded to the latest release, please try the push upgrade again.
>   Visit trust.salesforce.com for the salesforce.com release schedule.

The customers are waiting for the fix. How can I push upgrades today?

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if one org is on Spring'15 while the other is on Winter'15. The package-system can only be used within the same release.

My guess is that you push target is on a pre-release sandbox (cs17, cs19, some odd not an even number). First you installed the package a couple of weeks/days ago when you packaging org and the sandbox was on winter'15. Now the sandbox is update and your packaging org is not.

Until your packaging org has been updated you can only push to winter'15.